# merge skinnedeffect with basiceffect

Tags: xna

I'm developing a game with XNA 4.0. I have a very big model that I want to import in XNA with animations and later add LookAt constraints. To achieve this I import the model with SkinnedModelProcessor and add the lookAt constraints with [DigitalRune](http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/GameEngine/Animation.aspx) libraries.
My problem is due to the 72 MaxBones that SkinnedEffect can handle. If I want to import correctly the model I should add a bone for each mesh but the model has 152 distinct mesh and I can't split the model in submodels. If I don't add a bone for each mesh the processor throw this error "contains geometry without any vertex weights" forcing me to add a bone also to the mesh that I don't want to animate.

There is a way to import more than 72 bones? Or, alternatively, there is a way to merge in a single processor SkinnedEffect and BasicEffect in order to import skinned mesh (the ones with the associated bone) and mesh without a bone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3ds Max, you can skin each mesh that doesn't move with a single bone.

A link to the forum where this is answered:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/94840.aspx